# How to understand VBA file IO?

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code used to read in numbers in notepad and import it into excel 
format, but what does it mean? Especially the Array() part.

`Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Path, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(1, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(5, 1), _
    Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(45, 1), Array(50, 1), _
    Array(55, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(70, 1), Array(75, 1), Array(80, 1), Array(85, 1), Array(90, 1), Array(95, 1), Array(100, 1), _
    Array(105, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(120, 1), Array(125, 1), Array(130, 1), Array(135, 1), Array(140, 1), Array(145, 1), Array(160, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx -> FileInfo:= -> An array containing parse information for individual columns of data. ... data typ meanings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Array(a, b, c, ...)` simply creates a Variant array with the given elements. Thus, `Array(Array(a, b), Array(c, d), ...)` creates an array of arrays.
- The `FieldInfo` parameter of `OpenText` with the `xlFixedWith` option specifies the field boundaries ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx)):

> If the source data has fixed-width columns, the first element in each two-element array specifies the position of the starting character in the column (as an integer; character 0 (zero) is the first character). The second element in the two-element array specifies the parse option for the column as a number between 0 and 9, as listed in the preceding table.

Thus, the list can be read as follows:

```
Field   StartsAtPosition  Type
-------------------------------
  1         0             1
  2         1             1
  3         3             1
  4         5             1
  5        11             1
...
```

where Type 1 specifies that this is a "General" column (constant [`xlGeneralFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030.aspx)).